# Use cypress click with custom option

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have this custom method in cypress:

```
selectPanel: (panelName: string,) => {
  
    cy.get("[id=layout-editor-panel]").click("bottomRight");   
   
}
```

I want to pass an option in the method declaration in order to call the method with different click option - bottom, bottomRight, center etc. but facing some problems.

I have tried this without success:

```
selectPanel: (panelName: string,option: string) => {

    cy.get("[id=layout-editor-panel]").click("`${option}`");   
    
},
```

Help me understand where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the double-quotes around `option`, the backticks are enough. They are string delimiters as well.

In fact you don't even need backticks, since there is nothing else in the string except `option` - you can just use that as the `click()` parameter.

```js
selectPanel: (panelName: string, option: string) => {
   cy.get("[id=layout-editor-panel]").click(option);   
}
```

An example where you would need backticks, if `panelName` was the id of the element selected:

```js
selectPanel: (panelName: string, option: string) => {
   cy.get(`[id="${panelName}"]`).click(option);   
}
```